# How to fix error: "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically." message?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, anaconda, conda

I have been encountering this message after trying to import numpy, pandas, matplotlib, and seaborn all by themselves. I am not sure how to fix this. Any suggestions?

I am using Python 3.8.8, matplotlib 3.3.4, pandas 1.2.4, numpy 1.20.1, seaborn 0.11.1.

I have recently updated my Anaconda navigator to 2.1.0. Would this possibly have caused any issues?

In the shell command, after trying to import each of those packages individually, I see this message:
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_intel_thread.1.dylib.

Comment: Could you let us know which versions of the libraries you have installed on what version of python.  'python --version' and 'pip list' for the libraries

Comment: I am using Python 3.8.8, matplotlib 3.3.4, pandas 1.2.4, numpy 1.20.1, seaborn 0.11.1.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: I reinstalled Anaconda Navigator.

Answer (score -1):

If you using window 10 or 11, you can follow these steps for activating tensorflow and GPU CUDA in pycharm globally and handle that error:

1. Uninstall tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu (if using GPU) and reinstall again tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu:
   `pip tensorflow`
   `pip tensorflow-gpu`
2. Download and install CUDA (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) and cuDNN (https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn) if you have never downloaded before.
3. Unzip cuDNN zip folder and copy all files that in bin, include and lib folder to folder Nvidia GPU Computing Toolkit (C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.7)
4. Check GPU available in terminal using: 
   `import tensorflow as tf` 
   `tf.test.is_gpu_available()`
5. Run file python with pycharm and if show this error: 
   `the kernel for appears to have died. It will restart automatically.`
   Don't panic, follow this next steps.
6. Download zlibwapi.dll. zlibwapi will help to read cudnn from path running on local environment so we can use that globally. Download from this link: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html#install-zlib-windows
7. Right click on zlibwapi -> save link as -> and download the zip file of ZLIB DLL.
8. Unzip that file, and you can find zlibwapi.dll inside of folder dll_x64.
9. copied zlibwapi.dll to C:\Windows\System32 and C:\Windows\SysWOW64
10. Running again python file in pycharm that using CNN or ImageDataGenerator API from tensorflow, and see how it work.

In my case, this is work on my laptop. I hope this will help you.

Comment: The question doesn't even mention Tensorflow.

Comment: I think this question can use for any libraries or especially for pycharm/anaconda's problem error. Besides, this error happens when I run jupyter lab on anaconda. Firstly, I have some error with matplotlib when using pycharm or anaconda, and I use that solution and its work for me.

Comment: If you dont use tensorflow, I think you can follow steps from 6 to 10 to resolve it.